# Pandas Column Consists of Arrays, Plot This Using plt.imshow()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, imshow

So I have data that is structured in a slightly unusual way. Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict = {'data': [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]], 'parameter': [10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

In other words, each row in `df['data']` contains an array.

I need to plot this using matplotlib's `imshow()` function, but I'm having difficulties working with the arrays in `df['data']`. I've tried using `df['data'].to_numpy()`, but this returns a `dtype=object`, which imshow can't handle. I get this error when trying to plot it:

> TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

To be exact, this is what I've tried to run:

```
import pylab as plt
plt.imshow(df['data'].to_numpy())
```

I've read around and can't seem to find anyone with a similar example.

To be clear: I need to go *from* the DataFrame *to* imshow, I cannot plot directly from the dictionary in my code. I also do not want to do any appending to new lists, as my dataset is large and will slow things down considerably.

---

EDIT 1:

To answer a question in the comments, this is the type of plot I'm after. The x-axis contains the arrays in `df['data']`, while the y-axis will ultimately be `df['parameter']`.
[image]

---

EDIT 2:

I think I need to further clarify my question. I'm looking to reproduce this plot exactly.

[image]

To make this plot, I did the following:

```
rows = []
for i in df['data']: 
    rows.append(i)
plt.imshow(rows)
```

This solution works with my data, but I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing the same thing. i.e., a method that doesn't involve looping and appending.

Comment: What kind of plot you want? just plot it as square matrix? can it be that some lists will have different sizes?

Comment: @DavidS, I've added an edit. Let me know if this clarifies my goal.

Comment: does the x-axis consist of a flattened array from `df['data']?` If yes, does the range consist of the range of values for the flattened array from the entire(`df['data']`) column?

Comment: @theSekyi, the x-axis is exactly as I've laid out above. i.e., `y=df['parameter'][0]` and `x=df['data'][0]`, where x and y are the x-axis and y-axis values, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to unlist the `data` column to different rows and then plot.

```
x = df.explode('data').reset_index()
plt.imshow(x[['data','parameter']].to_numpy().astype('float').T)
```

This will produce:

[image]

Basically, `x[['data','parameter']].to_numpy().astype('float').T` will give you the desired numpy array where you can plot as you wish.

#### Edit based on user comment:

```
plt.imshow(np.array(df["data"].values.tolist()).astype('float'))
```

This will produce:

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, but not quite what I'm after. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: @NoVa so you don't want to use `parameter`?

Comment: I do, but for the sake of simplicity let's say no.

Comment: I only threw it in my first example to better replicate my data. `parameter` will really just be a y-label, it has no affect on the plotting outside of that.

Comment: hmm... I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float`.  That line of code correctly pulls out the arrays, but I'm still left with that original error.